# How to convert HTML to pdf file object in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, pdf

HTML -- 
`<h1>Hello World</h1>`

I have a scenario where I have ck editor in which i want to save contents of the editor as a pdf file in the server. But API is accepting the file object of the data present in the editor. So, I want a way in which I can the Html data to pdf file object and send that as a form Data json  object.
As of now, I am using 
 `new File([<h1>Hello World</h1>], this.state.fileName+".pdf", {
      type: "application/pdf",
      lastModified: new Date()
    });`
 to convert to file object.
But When i try to download it from from the server, it is giving me as error 
"Failed to load PDF document"

This html should be converted to pdf file and create an file object.